# Active directory logonCount is 0, though the user has logged in

Tags: networking, active-directory, network-programming, directoryservices, adsi

For a user in active directory, the properties hold values for lastlogontime & lastlogontimestamp but the logoncount is 0. I am having only one domain controller in that domain.

I found from surfing, that logonCount value of 0 indicates that the value is unknown. But I am totally confused with why it is unknown. Is that an issue with AD.

Comment: I know your question is kind of old (few months).  But, did you used to have another domain controller, or has it always been just the one?  Is LogonCount always 0 for all accounts or just for some accounts?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the PDC Emulator up and running on that DC.  You can check this from within ntdsutil or by right clicking the treeview in Active Directory Users and computers.

If the PDC is not available (possible DNS/wins issue) then perhaps that's the cause